# PHP email not delivered when user is on safari

Tags: php, email, safari

So I have a form to subscribe as a volunteer on an event I organize. Everything works fine for not mac/safari users. But when a user is on a mac ios/osx and he/she will fill in the form on safari, the email is never delivered. The database is filled with the users info, but the confirmation mail never reaches the user...

I'm using PHP mailer script.

This is my PHP code for the mailing part:

```
$subject = 'Bevestiging Vrijwilliger Dollen Dinsdag 2017';

        $message = $surname . ', bedankt voor je aanmelding!<br><br>';
        $message .= 'Om je inschrijving af te ronden vragen we je om deze te bevestigen door op de onderstaande link te drukken.<br><br>';
        $message .= '<a href="http://www.domain.nl/subscribe.php?action=confirm&userId='.$userId.'&userCode='.$confirmationCode.'">http://www.domain.nl/subscribe.php?action=confirm&userId='.$userId.'&userCode='.$confirmationCode.'</a><br>';
        $message .= 'Werkt de link niet door erop te klikken, kopieer en plak deze dan in je browser.<br><br>';
         $message .= 'Klopt deze aanmelding niet? klik dan <a href="http://www.domain.nl/subscribe.php?action=decline&userId=' .$userId. '&userCode=' .$confirmationCode. '">http://www.domain.nl/subscribe.php?action=decline&userId=' .$userId. 'userCode=' .$confirmationCode. '</a> om de aanmelding te annuleren.<br>';
        $message .= 'Werkt de link niet door erop te klikken, kopieer en plak deze dan in je browser.<br><br>';
        $message .= 'Met vriendelijke groet,<br>';
        $message .= 'Stichting Dollen Dinsdag';

        $headers = "Reply-To: Organization <info@domain.nl>".PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Return-Path: Dollen Dinsdag <info@dollendinsdag.nl>".PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "From: organization <info@domain.nl>".PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Organization: organization".PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 3".PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() .PHP_EOL;

        /////////////////////////

        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.nl';                  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'mail@domain.nl';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'pass';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('info@dollendinsdag.nl', 'Dollen Dinsdag');
        $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
        //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@dollendinsdag.nl', 'Vrijwilliger');
        //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
        //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

        //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
        //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $message;
        $mail->AltBody = $message;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'success';
        }
```

Comment: Considering PHP runs on the server I doubt the browser is affecting the sending of the mail.

Comment: Have you tried this, or had users try this, on any other devices or browsers?  If so, with what results?

Comment: PHP runs server-side, the OS or browser does not affect the mail sending script. Try validating the html inputs with both a working navigator (such as chrome) and safari. Once you find the difference, you can isolate the cause of the problem!

Comment: Also, how many users have reported the problem?  If it's only a few, there's a chance maybe they are using the same email provider, and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Is this on a Linux host? Does `$mail->send()` always result in "success" or are errors being thrown?

Comment: Everybody in the testpanels reports that they did not receive  confirmation mail, but when i look in the DB I see that the data of the form is stored properly. The mail clietns of the test persons er different. When they try it on chomre in iOs everythings works pereclty fine. I know PHP is server side, bud the clients browser/os is the only thing which is similar so far... Most beutifull part is that i do not ave an ios or mac-os device to test stuff on :-(

Comment: @BA_Webimax: no errors :-)

Comment: So no one is getting any of the emails?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `$email` is not being processed properly. I would try doing the following before pushing the variable to PHPMailer...

```
$email = preg_replace('~\R~u', "\r\n", $email);
$mail->addAddress($email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. It seems that there where some issues coming all together at once. I've looked with a frined of my to the code, and the mail problem seems to be that gmail has blacklisted mij account...